# Can we use IP address and process id combination instead of IP address and port number? Why and why not?

Tags: sockets, ip, port, pid

As we know in any web application for a tab in a browser there is one process so we require an ip address and a port number to identify the process. As we know for every tab there is unique port number. So for every process there is unique process id. Also instead of using ip and port number combination can we use ip and process id combination in socket programming. And if so then how? And if not why? Please can you help me.. Sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 3):

> Can we use IP address and process id combination instead of IP address and port number?

No.

> Why and why not?

Because they didn't define TCP/IP that way. It doesn't make sense. A remote computer doesn't have a way of discovering a process ID on another host. What it needs is a fixed number, i.e. a port number, which both hosts can implement.

> As we know for every tab there is unique port number.

This is absolutely and definitely incorrect. 'We' don't 'know' any such thing.

Answer (score 2):

> As we know in any web application for a tab in a browser there is one process

That is not guaranteed.  That is an implementation detail of the browser.  It may or may not use a separate process for each tab.

> so we require an ip address and a port number to identify the process.

No, you need an IP address and port to identify a given socket endpoint.  A process can have more than one socket active.

> As we know for every tab there is unique port number.

That is not guaranteed, either.  HTTP is stateless, and connections are not guaranteed or required to stay connected between requests, especially for long periods of time.  Say you open a tab and request a given website, leave the tab open for awhile, and then open a new tab to a different website.  The previous connection(s) may have been closed while the tab sat idle, and those port(s) may be available for re-use in the new tab.

> So for every process there is unique process id.

That is the only thing that is guaranteed in this situation.  But remember that once a process ends, its process id can and will be re-used in a subsequent new process.

> Also instead of using ip and port number combination can we use ip and process id combination in socket programming.

No.  But on some platforms, such as Windows, there are APIs available to discover the process ID that owns a given socket, at least.

> if not why?

Because that is not how sockets are designed to operate.  A socket endpoint is identified by its protocol/IP/port tuple, and a socket connection is identified by the protocol/IP/port tuple of the two peers that are connected to each other.  Remember that a socket connection can span across machine boundaries, but a process ID is only local to the machine it is running on.